# how to abort all incomplete multipart uploads for a bucket in SDK : java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, lifecycle

how to abort all incomplete multipart uploads for a bucket

So, as a context, I am using an AmazinS3 client with multipart upload to the upload files under a directory every day. Now want to add a bucketLifecycle policy to abort failed multipart uploads.

I have tried to do the same with the below piece of code but it throws an error saying "abortincompletemultipartupload rules are not supported."

Also, I cannot add a lifecycle policy through CLI or any command. Need to handle through code only

```
AbortIncompleteMultipartUplaod abort = new AbortIncompleteMultipartUplaod();
abort.setDaysAfterInitialtion(1);

BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule rule1 = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                .withId("delete failed uplaod")
                .withPrefix("")
                .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED)
                .withAbortIncompleteMultipartUpload(abort);

BucketLifecycleConfiguration configuration = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration()
                .withRules(Arrays.asList(rule1));

//creation of S3 client

s3Client.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName, configuration);
```